# Do kill skills stack?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have no high level characters in Borderlands 2 and was wondering if someone could test if kill skills stack?

Do several "kill skills" traits activate on a single kill?

Comment: This user last visited "Jan 13 at 13:51" and the question seems to be definitively answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do. You can have as many kill skills active as you have specced into.

Answer (score 1):

Kill skills stack, but a particular kill skill can only be active a single time. Activating it again will refresh the duration instead of applying another instance of the effect.